# How to integrate $\oint_{c}(\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{r})d\textbf{r}$ where $(\textbf{A}$ is constance and $c$ is a circular path

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, vector-fields

I think this should give some vector in the plane of the circle (which I will call the x-y plane for simplicity), with the direction of the vector dependent on the vector, $\textbf{A}$. More specifically,  think the integral should be given by
$$\oint_{c}(\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{r})d\textbf{r}=\pi R^{2}\hat{\textbf{z}}\times\textbf{A}$$where $R$ is the radius of the circle,
however my attempts to integrate have given zero. My method is as follows, express
$$\textbf{r}=R\hat{\textbf{r}}$$
and
$$d\textbf{r}=R\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}d\theta$$
where I have used the basis vectors,
$$\hat{\textbf{r}}=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0)$$
and
$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}=(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta,0)$$and then integrating $\theta$ over $2\pi$,
$$R^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(A_{x}\cos\theta+A_{y}\sin\theta\right)\begin{pmatrix}-\sin\theta \\ \cos\theta\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}d\theta$$
since trig functions evaluate to zero over a full period. Have I done something wrong here?

Comment: $$\left(A_{x}\cos\theta+A_{y}\sin\theta\right) \begin{pmatrix}-\sin\theta \\ \cos\theta\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-A_x \cos \theta \sin\theta - A_y \sin^2 \theta \\ A_x \cos^2 \theta + A_y \cos \theta \sin \theta\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$and the functions $\cos^2 \theta$ and $\sin^2 \theta$ don't integrate to zero over a full period.